# angular translate - access retrieved json

Tags: angularjs, translate

I'm using Pascal Precht angular-translate. I use useStaticFilesLoader to load langs from json.

How could I access the retrieved json ? I have to count how many keys I have to display in sub-objects.

EDIT: 
My goal is to avoid to launch another $http request each time I load a lang. I would like to access the lang loaded by angular-translate.